# Canna turning brown and yellow HELP

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, indoors, canna

My plant has a few leaves turning yellow and brown. This happened after I watered it this weekend, help!! I really love my plant, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: That actually looks like Strelitzia Reginae or Bird of Paradise not a Canna Lily,  is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I see white dots on the leaves which are a type of scale. There are many different types but I believe this to be Boisduval scale (scientific name: Diaspis boisduvalii) which is described [here](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/Creatures/orn/scales/boisduval_scale.htm). I think your plant is a Bird of Paradise or Strelitzia reginae which is listed as a subject to attack by the scale [here](http://scalenet.info/catalogue/diaspis%20boisduvalii/)

Poor pest control at the grower is the most likely way it arrived with the plant.

Control is hard as the scale hides inside the leaf sheaths and the waxy coating is resistant to soap and water.

You can try this:

- isolate the plant as the scales can fly to other plants
- use isopropyl alcohol and a cloth or cotton swab to wipe away the scales
- repeat at five to seven day intervals at least three or four times or as necessary

Comment: Dish soap can also help get a tooth brush and put some dish soap on the plant then scrub.